# Changing automatically the arguments of a function

Tags: parametric-functions

I have a function of the type:

```
f[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]
```

I would like to evaluate the function changing the values of the arguments automatically. For instance varying `a` from 0 to 1 with a given step, keeping the other arguments constant, and varying after also all the other arguments with different intervals and steps. 
For instance: {a,b,c,d,e,f} with intervals 0 to 1 with step 0.1; and {g,h,i} with intervals {0 to Pi/4}, with step Pi/16.
I'm sure there is an efficient way to do this, without having to write an immense table.

**UPDATE**

My final goal is to random sample my set of arguments. As BlacKow pointed out, I would have 84375 points to evaluate. Since I have quite a heavy function, this would take way too much time. So I would rather attempt to random sample it. Following BlacKows definition, I would have something like,

```
RandomSample[points, 300];
```

Anyhow, I think both answers were very useful.

Comment: "Immense table"? I'm not sure why that would be bad. The other alternative would be to generate the ranges of values and `MapThread` your function over it, but it still seems to me that a `Table` with multiple iterators would be the most natural solution.

Comment: Yes, I already thought of table. Yet having there to be variables having the same interval and the same step, I thought it might have been possible to change such variables in a more tidy way.

Comment: Would you please include appropriate `Table` code in your question that does what you want, so people know exactly what you want to accomplish and have a point of comparison for their improved solutions?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate argument vectors:

```
points = Partition[#, 8] &@
   Flatten@Tuples[{Tuples[Range[0, 1, 0.25], 5], 
      Tuples[Range[0, Pi/4, Pi/8], 3]}];

Dimensions[points]
(*{84375, 8} equals to 5^5*3^3 *)
```

and then `f@@@points`

> **Update** If you need a random sample in the 8-dimensional space, you need following

```
samplPoints[n_] := # {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, Pi/4, Pi/4, Pi/4} & /@ 
   RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 8}];
samplPoints[10]
```

It will generate 10 points in 8D.

Comment: Your solution probably best fits my problem. Indeed my next step would be to use a RandomSample, or a Latin Hypercube.

Comment: @MirkoAveta it's not much different form @kglr. Also you have to check which one is faster for your application. I just though applying `Tuples` to `Tuples would be cool.

Comment: Yes they both return the same result. Fair enough! I was just wondering which is best for random sampling. For my very heavy function, 84375 points is impossible! (time is time...)

Comment: @MirkoAveta Now I'm confused. You don't want to apply you function to all of these points? You just want some sort of Monte-Carlo sample of your 8-dimensional space? Then, the code will be different...

Comment: Yes I just wanted a list from whom pick randomly a smaller set of points. I didn't say so in my question, so you are rightfully confused. I'll edit it right now.

Comment: @MirkoAveta See my update. It's way easier to do what you actually need.

Comment: Yeah, but I guess that in this way I don't sample my points with the same "steps" I wanted, right?

Comment: @MirkoAveta No, you don't. but if you randomly choose from 84375 points you won't sample at the same steps either.

Comment: Yes, I realized that.

Comment: also with RandomSample it also messes up the order of my variables, like Pi related variables end up moving to the first arguments...

Comment: @MirkoAveta if you use my updated code, the Pi related variables are always in the end.

Comment: Yes, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

smaller version of the problem with a function with 5 arguments:

```
h @@@ Tuples[Join[ConstantArray[Range[0, 1, .2], 3],
                  ConstantArray[Range[0, Pi/4, Pi/16], 2]]]
```

or

```
Tuples[h @@ Join[ConstantArray[Range[0, 1, .2], 3],
                ConstantArray[Range[0, Pi/4, Pi/16], 2]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: kglr may I ask you why there are three at signs?

Comment: @Mirko, regarding  `@@@` and `@@` see the docs: [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html)